# View @ supressed errors in php

Tags: php

I know you can use @ to suppress errors.
But is there anyway you can make php ignore @ ?

In my case, I have to use a 3th party script that uses @, the script is huge and I'm having a hard time finding out where it dies.

Comment: Suggest you just edit them all out. Try initially with a global search/replace. If that does more than it should then just do it by hand.

Comment: use regular expression to remove `@` with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the [PHP Xdebug extension](http://www.xdebug.org/) you can ignore the [error control operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `@` by using [this config setting](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#scream):

```
xdebug.scream = 1
```

This disables the @ (shut-up) operator so that notices, warnings and errors are no longer hidden.

Answer (score 4):

There's the [scream extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.scream.php) to break the silence.

Comment: How nice to see this suggested by a guy with headphones.

Comment: @Pekka My 'phones are my personal `@` operator. :o)

Answer (score 2):

**Every custom error handler** receives suppressed error messages:

```
set_error_handler("var_dump");
```

Just an example. You would normally choose a nicer reporting function.

Answer (score 1):

> But is there anyway you can make php ignore @ ?

I don't think so, no, not without an extension as shown by @deceze.

You could set up a [custom error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) though. If you configure that to ignore the `error_reporting()` setting, which is `0` when inside a function that was called with `@`, you can output the error there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```

to get the last generated error after that script so you can catch the supressed errors.

Further reading [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('scream.enabled', true);
```

You need to install the scream pecl extension:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.scream.php